# Proof of different sizes between similar infinite sets

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I wish you a fantastic day!

Let's define $\mathbb N$ as the set of all $n≥0$.
Let's define $\mathbb N^*$ as the set of all $n>0$.

My target within a larger problem is to try and prove that a function defined as

$$f : \mathbb N^* \to  \mathbb N$$

can't be a bijection.

This is, in my reasoning, because there are *more* elements in the second set. That is, $0$ is in $\mathbb N$, but not in $\mathbb N^*$ and as such, **$\mathbb N$ is bigger**.

$$\mathrm{card}(\mathbb N) > \mathrm{card}(\mathbb N^*)$$

Where card = number of elements

However, I can't find a reasonable and satisfactory way of proving this. I have tried proving by association, that is:

> Let every element from the first set be paired with the element of the same index from the second set. Since the $\mathbb N^*$ is going to use **all and just the elements from $\mathbb N \setminus \{0\}$**, $\mathbb N$ has one additional element.

Thank you for reading this and thanks in advance!

Comment: It is (famously) false, for example, $f : \Bbb{N}^* \to \Bbb{N} : x \mapsto x - 1$ is bijective (see [Hilbert's Hotel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_paradox_of_the_Grand_Hotel)). Indeed, any infinite set can be placed in bijection with a strict subset (and this is sometimes taken as the definition of an infinite set).

Comment: Notice I edited your question to improve the formatting. It is strongly advised that you use Mathjax to format your questions on this site - it's like LaTeX for the web. I edited your question this time since you are new, but in future, please format the question yourself. See here for a quick guide: [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: So more you'll be surprised that, for instance, the map $f:\Bbb Z\to 2\Bbb Z$, defined by $x\mapsto 2x$, is a bijection as well. Therefore, the even integers are "as many as" all the integers (and the same holds for any $n$ in place of $2$).

Comment: You recieved an answer to your question. Is it what you needed? If so, consider accepting the answer. That's how the site works. If it is not what you needed, please explain what is still left unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are proving cannot be proven, because a bijection does exist.

The mapping $f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N^*$ defined as $f(n) = n+1$ is a bijection between $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb N^*$.